# Angularjs http.get failure (but I see the data was returned)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm walking thru the Angularjs phones tutorial and want to get the phones JSON from a remote server.

```
$http.get('http://myserver.com/phones.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.phones = data;
});
```

This failed due to CORS, I was sending an OPTIONS not a GET request, so I added this first line to the controller

```
delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

I can see now in Charles that a GET not OPTIONS request is being made to myserver.com, and that the phones JSON is in the response. But the http.get is still failing with status 0 and 'data' is null.

Not sure what to try next. Any insights appreciated.

Comment: Try adding `?callback=?` to the end of your url

Answer (score 2):

It should not be making an OPTIONS request for a GET, so that sounds right. I think what you want to do is:

```
$http.get('http://myserver.com/phones.json').then(function(data) {
  $scope.phones = data;
}, function(err) { alert('Oh no! An error!'});
```

I think you want to use `then()`, which takes two functions as arguments — the first for success, and the second for error. `$http.get()` returns a promise which is acted upon by `then()`.

Also, you probably want to use `$resource` instead of `$http`. It provides a higher level of abstraction, and allows for a more reusable style, http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource

EDIT:

Check out the angular debug tool [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en). It shows you what is available in scopes, and shows performance data.

Comment: It should work as is. Tutorial states " $http.get service returns a promise object with a success method. We call this method to handle the asynchronous response and assign the phone data to the scope". I have used **then** with **success & error** blocks with the same result,  written this as a service, etc.  My goal is the simplest http request demo, not a resource call. I always see the JSON in the Charles response but http.get returns status 0.  So far I've found no cross-domain example apps out there just local flat file examples.

Comment: try adding `$http.defaults.useXDomain = true;`

Comment: Thanks, no luck with that, still status code 0, this to be a big limitation with Angular. I'll look into using the http.jsonp method which does not use XHR.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are making a cross domain request, it is right to make a OPTION request as a [pre-flight request](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) to know if you are allowed to.
If the CORS fails your browser will receive the data but it'll throw an error.
So, either you put your html in the same domain or add the CORS to your backend (which is more difficult).

Comment: I got around the CORS issue. But speaking of CORS what is so unusual about an app wanting to make cross-domain requests?  How would an Angular app call 5 distributed geographic services which can't be tweaked?

Comment: It's a browser's security issue called SOR (Same Origin Police). Well [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) it's a HTML5 feature which is about to make it usual, now you can do a Cross-site request without any hack.

Comment: Here's a great tutorial that answers my question.

Comment: I'll advise you to use CORS, jsonp it is a hack.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good tutorial which implements cross-domain GETS using the $http.jsonp method.  No hacks to the headers.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/building-a-web-app-from-scratch-in-angularjs/